# Use of explicit as a verb

Tags: grammaticality, zero-derivation

Can we use *explicit* as a verb?

For instance, is it correct to say *to explicit it further*? I have searched it on Google however, *explicit* is either described as adjective or noun.

Comment: What do you think _to explicit it further_ would mean?

Comment: What's wrong with _explain_?

Comment: What would the sense be? To make obvious? To state something aloud?

Comment: Use *to make it more explicit* rather than *to explicit it further*.

Answer (score 2):

In English ***verbing*** is common, but in order for adjectives to become verbs you need suffixes like
 *-ize, -ify* etc. (See *Verb Suffixes*, [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/suffixes))

***Explicit*** is not commonly used as a verb, though it may have been in the past, as @GEdgar says in his answer. You will find the rather obscure *[explicitize](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/explicitize)* in few dictionaries, but the most idiomatic is to use ***to make explicit***. If you need an enhancement, you can use *to make **more** explicit*.

Otherwise, there are [plenty of synonyms](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-verb-for/explicit.html) that you could use instead.

Comment: Notice how in [this rendering of your post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SACog.png) there is an incorrect line-break right after the hyphen in your *ize* suffix. “But how to mend such minutiae?” I hear you silently wondering. Instead of using the `-` character, which is Unicode code point `U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS`, you replace it with the lookalike `‑` character, which is Unicode code point `U+2011 NON-BREAKING HYPHEN`, and lo the problem is no more! That’s because those two characters differ in their underlying line-breaking properties, which drive how and where modern rendering engines break lines.

Comment: I managed in a different way ;) !

Answer (score 2):

The *Oxford English Dictionary* has a verb *expicit*, marked "obsolete".  It means "here ends...".

For example, Mallory in *Morte Darthur* (1470) has "Explicit the weddyng of kyng Arthur" to mark the end of the telling of the wedding of King Arthur.

Comment: The **intransitive** verb did indeed mean "end", but it was used only in the 3rd person singular present tense. So you couldn't explicit anything. On the other hand, the [rare but also-obsolete **transitive** version](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/66635) with an object is glossed to mean opening the petals of something, an old sense of "explicate" but with an expansive sense.